# Apache - Dynamic Subdomains

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system

I'm facing an issue with setting up my development environment. I'm trying to server all my projects as subdomains.

Here's the structure of my LAN network:

```
192.168.1.15 - PC
192.168.1.16 - Laptop
192.168.1.17 - Laptop
192.168.1.20 - Dev Server
```

I've successfully configured Apache dynamic subdomains using **mod_vhost_alias** Apache module and **dnsmasq** DNS server.

Here's configuration of my Apache virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/html/%1/web/"

  <Directory "/var/www/html/%1/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/dnsmasq.conf file

```
listen-address=127.0.0.1
address=/.dev/127.0.0.1
```

As you surely see, I'm able to access my projects located in `/var/www/html/` dynamically, without creating new virtual host or editing `/etc/hosts` file. Everything works perfectly and really speeds up the development process. I should say, it was working before I migrated development server to separate machine.

What is the issue? How to make working this config in local network? (I don't need the server to be accessible from the Internet).

I have added an entry to Windows hosts `file` on my PC pointing `192.168.1.20` IP address to `dev` hostname however I have no idea how to make subdomains working.

Comment: As with any migration, check the logs for errors and tell us what you see :)

Comment: While accessing from the server, everything is working perfectly. When I try to access test.dev from my PC or laptop, browser is unable to find such website. Any ideas? :)

Comment: Add the subdomains to the hosts file on each machine or configure dnsmasq to answer those queries. See the dnsmasq man page for details on this. It could be that it is enough to add these in the hosts file of the server that runs dnsmasq.

Comment: @AndreasM - Unfortunately this is not a solution for me, I thought about it before posting this question. Why? I'm often traveling and then taking the server with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably easiest to edit your hosts file on each machine to add the sub domains that you want to resolve. The format of the hosts file is quite simple

```
ip.add.re.ss    hostname.tld sub1.hostname.tld sub2.hostname.tld
```

or
    ip.add.re.ss    hostnname.tld
    ip.add.re.ss    sub.hostname.tld

so you can have

```
192.168.1.20    mydev.lan test.mydev.lan deploy.mydev.lan
```

or

```
192.168.1.20    mydev.lan
192.168.1.20    test.mydev.lan deply.mydev.lan
```

The thing to note here is you get the first match on hostname is returned.

Alternatively you could allow dnsmasq to listen on the server's IP address and set it as the DNS server for your other machines.

Comment: Iain - Unfortunately this is not a solution for me, I thought about it before posting this question. Why? I'm often traveling and then taking the server with me. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @Jason what is the problem then? Switch apache off while travelling or switch the firewall on, no?

Comment: Just for the future, any details on `Alternatively you could allow dnsmasq to listen on the server's IP address and set it as the DNS server for your other machines.`?

Comment: You have specified listen-address as 127.0.0.0 so dnsmasq is only listening on the loopback address. If you don't specify a listen-address then it will listen on all available interfaces. Similarly you can put address=/.dev/192.168.1.20 and then point the other machines at the server for dns.